# Popover filled white and coloured border

Tags: css, popover

I got this code:

```
<ul>
    <li> 
        <a href="#"></a>
        <div class="container"></div>
        <div class="data"></div>
    </li>
</ul>

// --------------------------- CSS -------------------------- //

.data:before {
    content:'';
    float: right;
    margin: -15px 15px;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 15px solid red;
}

.data {
    background-color: white;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

How can i make my triangle (popover) be white filled and red border? As its made with "border" propperty, could i use a shadow?

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dieguezz/n68tcfjs/3/)

Comment: Not with a shadow as it's a **box** shadow not a triangle shadow. - http://jsfiddle.net/n68tcfjs/5/

Comment: any ideas on how to achieve it? i am thinking on using bootstrap's http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Comment: You need to use another pseudo-element on top of the original one. It's messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:before` and `after`

```css
.data:before,.data:after{
    content:'';
    float: right;
}
.data:before {
    margin: -15px 15px;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 15px solid red;
}
.data:after {
    margin: -12px 20px;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid white;
}
.data {
    background-color: white;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li> 
        <a href="#"></a>
        <div class="container"></div>
        <div class="data"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

or use `rotate`

```css
.data:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    top:-11px;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    border:2px solid red;
    border-right:none;
    border-bottom:none;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.data {
    background-color: white;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    position:relative
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li> 
        <a href="#"></a>
        <div class="container"></div>
        <div class="data"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```